# Pytorch: encode categorical feature by using nn.Embedding

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch. I learnt some tutorials about how to build a simple NN model by using pytorch, e.g. ([this one](https://yashuseth.blog/2018/07/22/pytorch-neural-network-for-tabular-data-with-categorical-embeddings/)). I find that they prefer to nn.Embedding to encode categorical features. My questions are: (1) why not use one hot encoding? (2) nn.Embedding is initialized randomly, and I think the numerical values of the embeddings will not be trained because they are treated as input. If the nn.Embedding initializes the categorical features randomly, would it have a negative impact to the training?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Embeddings are usually lower dimensional and continuous. That makes them more suitable for NN training.

(2) They should be trained if you have just initialized them. They are considered part of your model, kind of like a junction connecting one-hot encoded values with the rest of your model.

Comment: But I guess the values of the embeddings are not changed during training because the features are treated as input, which is fixed?

Comment: @JYY in a neural network almost everything is an input to the next layer. That doesn't prevent it to be trainable. In fact it is just a linear projection layer.